# Is ASP.NET MVC 4 packaged with .NET Framework 4.5.1?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, web-deployment, .net-4.5

If I install .NET 4.5.1 on a server, providing IIS is already there, will it be able to run a site that uses ASP.NET MVC 4?

Or, am I required to download and install ASP.NET MVC 4 as a separate package?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC 4 and 5 are both available as nuget packages, so just make sure that those assemblies are in the bin folder when you publish.

An IIS server with .NET 4.5.1 can run an MVC website as long as those dlls are available, either in the GAC or in the bin folder of the web application. I'd suggest that you go the bin folder route.

Aslo, [ASP.NET Web Deployment](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/introduction) has some documentation on using web deploy

Comment: So just to clarify, .NET 4.5.1 (RTM), will not run a website built on ASP.NET MVC 4, correct?

Comment: It will run it the website.. sure. It won't come installed with MVC for you though.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now.  ASP.NET MVC 4 is not bundled with .NET 4.5.1, however, if you deploy the MVC 4 dlls along with your application, it should all work.